# Ubuntu 11.04 on a ARCHOS 101 Internet Tablet?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook, tablet

Does anyone have experience with the ARCHOS 101 Internet Tablet 8gb or 16gb.

Can I install Ubuntu 11.04 on it?

Can I dual boot Ubuntu / Android?

[Specs on Archos](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_101it/specs.html)

Comment: it's an ARM device, you need a version with support for ARM, the regular x86 and x86_64  versions just won't work.Also there were posts floating around the net about installing Debian or Ubuntu in a Nexus One and the HTC HD2, maybe you can try those on the tablet.

Comment: Cool thanks. I am a little afraid that Archos only has 256mb of RAM and I can see the Nexus one has 512mb ram, maybe this can cause some problems.
I have not bought it yet, because I really want both operating systems on it,ps it must lie in this price range.

Comment: I just got confirmation from Archos that it only has 256mb ram, but they say they will come with a new generation of products, is due to be released in the final quarter of this year and will have improved specs.

Comment: You Should wait then :), or Try to Install Lubuntu on the archos 101, Lubuntu needs less RAM than vanilla Ubutntu

Comment: I do not really think that Lubuntu's UI will be great on a tablet. So yes I think I just wait ;)

Comment: you can always customize The GUI.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for the Archos 101 Internet Tablet in Ubuntu is a work-in-progress.  The wiki page describing the current state of these efforts is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OMAP/Archos101it

Note that due to the relatively low memory available for this device, support is never expected to be wonderful: those who do not currently own such a device would be better served by something with a bit more RAM (Archos's G9 series is one example).

Users who have installed Ubuntu on devices with 4GB or 8GB of local storage have expressed a sense of confinement in terms of available storage for common data: while the environment works, devices with 16GB of local storage have received more positive reviews.

You will not be able to use Unity in Ubuntu 11.04 on this device: Unity support for GLES is too new: while it is hoped that it can be included in Ubuntu 11.10, this has not yet been confirmed.

I am not personally familiar with the bootloader configuration for the Archos tablets, but people with similar devices have reported that dual-booting is difficult.  In the special circumstance of dual-booting between Android and Ubuntu, you will want to have completely different areas of storage used for each system, which will expand your storage requirements.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you don't have much experience with the more intricate side of coding, or programing. Basically just install or is their just the long "code like" way that the wiki has?